# Problem with file iris_dri.so

Tags: 20.04, files

I need help, delete the file iris_dri.so because I confused it and now certain programs are much slower than usual. What I can do?

It should be clarified, I have Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That library appears to be part of [the `libgl1-mesa-dri` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=iris_dri.so), so you will need to re-install it to ensure you have all of your files.

You can do so from the Terminal like this:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Try to be a bit more careful with the `rm` command, as there is not always a simple fix

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @N0rbert 